# CodeIgniter session 'set_userdata' does not work

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am trying to start the session with *CodeIgniter*, but it does not show any error either. I tried to change the session's driver to database and also I tried to specify the session path, but I didn't work.

```
$session_data = array(
                   'is_login'     => TRUE,
                   'username'     => $user->username,
                   'id'           => $user->id, 
                   'type'         => $user->type,
                   'name'         => $user->name,
                   );
$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

From Comment

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files'; 
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session'; 
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200; 
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir(); 
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE; 
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300; 
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Did you load the session driver? What does "it does not work" mean? Post your session configuration details.

Comment: Show your config session settings.

Comment: You have your save path wrong.

Comment: Try something like `$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/'; ` Have 0700 for folder permission.  Auto load the session library this `sys_get_temp_dir()` incorrect

Answer (score 0):

First open the file located at `application/config/autoload.php`

Find the following section.

The `$autoload['libraries'] = array();` array holds the list of libraries that need to be autoloaded.

As per our requirement, let's change it to look like this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Also, there's another way you could have achieved that. You can use the following code somewhere in your controller file to load the session library.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```